# Scheduler Class error

Tags: apex, soql, scheduled-apex, dynamic-soql

I am writing a Scheduler Class to send out mass Emails(HTML email template) based on the time I schedule, below is my code

```
global class pS implements Database.batchable<sObject> , Database.Stateful{

private EmailTemplate emailTemp;
global pS(){
    emailTemp = [Select Id From EmailTemplate Where Name = 'SP']; 
}

global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
    String query = 'Select Id, Lastname, Firstname, Email From Contact WHERE ((Account.RecordType.Id = \'01239000000Nabc\' AND Account.premier__c = False) OR (RecordType.Id = \'01239000000Ncdd\' AND Account.Status__c = "Processing")) AND Account.Name != "Test" AND Email != null AND HasOptedOutOfEmail = False';
    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
}

global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Contact> scope){           

    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
    for(Contact con : scope) {
         if(emailTemp != null && con.Email != null && con.Email != '') {
           Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
           email.setToAddresses(new List<String>{con.Email}); 
           email.setTargetObjectId(con.Id);                   
           email.setTemplateId(emailTemp.Id);
           email.setTreatTargetObjectAsRecipient(true);        
           emails.add(email);                                      
        }          
    Messaging.sendEmail(emails);
    }                
}   
global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
}
}
```

when I run this class I receive this error

```
14:46:18:012 FATAL_ERROR System.QueryException: line 1:215 no viable alternative at character '"'
```

But when I change my "String query" to below I do not receive any error, also I am receiving emails

```
String query = 'Select Id, Lastname, Firstname, Email From Contact WHERE Account.RecordType.Id = \'01239000000Nabc\' AND Account.premier__c = False
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: Do *not* use a string query when an inline query will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use double quotes (`"..."`) in SOQL. Use single quotes instead (`'...'`). This behavior is documented in the `Force.com SOQL and SOSL Reference` under [*`fieldExpression`* syntax](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_fieldexpression.htm):

> If quotes are required (for example, they are not for dates and numbers), use single quotes. Double quotes result in an error.

Comment: Sorry! I didn't know that, will be careful from next time, thanks.

Comment: Thanks Adrian! I just replaced the "..." to \'...\' and it is working now my new query is

String query = 'Select Id, Lastname, Firstname, Email From Contact WHERE ((Account.RecordType.Id = \'01239000000Nabc\' AND Account.premier__c = False) OR (RecordType.Id = \'01239000000Ncdd\' AND Account.Status__c = '\Processing\')) AND Account.Name != '\Test\' AND Email != null AND HasOptedOutOfEmail = False';

Comment: I am receiving two emails, one with Attachment and the other without Attachment. It is not Plain Text as well. Any idea why is this happening? thanks.

Comment: Please do not ask entirely different questions as a `Comment`. Your initial issue is resolved. If you face others please pose a new `Question`.